# Calling JS function(AJAX) within the same page from a form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to execute a AJAX function script in the same page after the user enters a text and presses a submit button.

After submitting, the AJAX script will send the result over to findme.php which perform a query on the database. The query on findme.php is working as i have tested it before implementing the ajax function.

I have adopted the method from [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) but to no available. I wasnt able to call the script and send the values over to findme.php

Does anyone know what i have done wrongly ?

**qwerty.php**

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","findme.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

 <tr>
<form name="search" method="post" action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="findName"/>
Location: <input type="text" name="findLocation"/>
Price: <input type="text" name="findPrice"/>
<Select NAME="123">
<Option type="checkbox" value="">
<Option type="checkbox" value="=">Equal
<Option type="checkbox" value="<">Less than
<Option type="checkbox" value=">">More than
</select>

<input onclick="showUser(); return false;" type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
</form>

  </tr>
<tr>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have solved the calling of function issue. However i am trying to pass multiple values over to findme.php is there something i can change to the script to get it pass multiple values ? Cheers

Comment: I would suggest you (as i already did) to see jQuery.post() link, cause it got examples for better posting multiplie data to any php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return false after calling the function, else the form is submitting which causes to lose the ajax call.

```
<input onclick="showUser(); return false;" type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: thanks Daan. Can i check with you for my case, as i have multiple input field, do i have to be concern about the method that i am using. It seems that they are using string.
`function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;`

Comment: Remove return when str is empty else the rest of the function isn't executed. Unless you want to of course

Comment: Doesnt work for my case even after removing the ifempty check. I am thinking it is because of `xmlhttp.open("GET","findme.php?q="+str,true);` Any thoughts on it.

Comment: str can't be empty when posting the ajax call. Try to input something manually

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using input type = "submit" , try onSubmit event on the form.
asa

`<form name="search" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return showUser();">`

Dont forget the `return` keyword . Return `false` in showUser(); when str=="" and like that.